# Ruby on Rails: replace_html not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this div

```
<div id="result_text"></div>
```

And I try doing

```
render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html :result_text, "<div style='font-size:medium;padding-top:25px;'>Thank you. A message has been sent to #{@object.user.name} with your comments.</div>"
```

I know the method is getting invoked.  but the div doesn't get the new text.. =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
page.replace_html 'result_text', "<div style='font-size:medium;padding-top:25px;'>Thank you. A message has been sent to #{@object.user.name} with your comments.</div>"
```